# Flutter Navigator.replace() example

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to replace my current screen and found `replace` method in Navigator's API. But I didn't find any example for it. Maybe somebody knows how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if [`replace`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/replace.html) is what you are looking for. You can take a look at the [Navigator *class*](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html).

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Yep, I looked at this class, and I need to open a new screen without a possibility to close it and return on previous one. Just first screen is a login screen.

Answer (score 66):

I usually use

```
Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage());
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html

Comment: This is not an example of `Navigator.replace` but of `Navigator.pushReplacement`

Answer (score 23):

I have never used `Navigator.replace()` but this  `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` might help you.

```html
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/thread_list');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method doesn't work. Looks like I should just replace the body of the main widget by setState() method.

Comment: to use this, you need to declare a route definition when runApp

Comment: It really works, and for me it was the best solution.
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');

Comment: `Navigator.pushReplacement` replace current router to new. But it's not clear all history. For example Login -> (Add) Register (Replace) -> Home (Click Back button) -> Login

Answer (score 5):

If you also want to pop all the routes on the `Navigator` stack, use

```dart
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/page2', (route) => false);
```

or

```dart
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, 
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2()), (route) => false);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can  also use:

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/example');
```

Answer (score -2):

Here the doc of Navigator.dart

> Replaces a route on the navigator that most tightly encloses the given context with a new route.
> The old route must not be currently visible, as this method skips the animations and therefore the removal would be jarring if it was visible.
> To replace the top-most route, consider [pushReplacement] instead, which *does* animate the new route, and delays removing the old route until the new route has finished animating.

```
@optionalTypeArgs
  static void replace<T extends Object?>(BuildContext context, { required Route<dynamic> oldRoute, required Route<T> newRoute }) {
    return Navigator.of(context).replace<T>(oldRoute: oldRoute, newRoute: newRoute);
  }
```

replace method is like

```
Navigator.replace(
    context,
    oldRoute: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OlRoute()),
    newRoute: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewRoute()),
  );
```

Comment: copy paste a text from the documentation  doesn't count as an answer, please make your next answer more specific and helpful

Comment: at least, did you read the whole answer? The last code looks like a good example